# Can you move system.diagnostics configuration from web.config in appsettings.json for iConfiguration for a .NET Framework 4.6.1 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, configuration

Our team is trying to move our web.config transforms into appsettings.json files which are determined in runtime via an environment variable in the server which we set on deploy (rather than transforming web.config files at compile time). One of our projects has a web.config with system.diagnostics logging configuration which is transformed using xdt transform. We are not moving to ASP.NET Core (yet), but sticking with ASP.NET Framework 4.6.1 (we are forced due to our solution being tied to a particular version of Sitecore which we can't upgrade due to licensing).

Can we move system.diagnostics configuration into an appsettings.json file which is then picked up by iConfiguration? If so, how would we do it? How is the configuration for diagnostics structured in the json file?

Secondary bonus but related question: We have system.web and system.webserver configurations that are also transformed. Can they be similarly moved to an appsettings.json file as well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're not moving to .Net Core, how are you going to have access to its configuration mechanism ?

Comment: @sh1rts you can by using iConfiguration and manually pull in the file upon object creation. Generally you either combine this with a singleton static class or better yet a dependency injector and pass into the classes you wish to add configuration to. That part we know how to do.